# Firefox not following php header redirect without www

Tags: php, firefox, redirect, header

I have this code:

```
if($_REQUEST["lang"]!="") {
    /* Random language assigments */
    header("location: ".$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); //Return to referring page having changed the language
}
```

Which is working fine in Chrome and Firefox in PC and iOS, except on Firefox in iOS when the referring url doesn't begin with www. What could be happening?

Edit: If I substitute REQUEST for GET it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

After noticing it worked fine when using _GET instead of _REQUEST I concluded there was a cookie problem interfering with where the page was soliciting the _REQUEST, probably giving priority to a trash cookie left over or something. Clearing cookies or specifying _GET solved the problem.